# HTML5 storage partitioning or tables

Tags: html

Is there a concept of tables (in relational database) or partitions in most implementation of HTML5 Storage specification (or specifically IE10s/Windows 8 Metro)?
I'd like to store multiple types of data and would like to get easy access to them. e.g.
Retrieve all items of type A (or from Table/partition A).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several HTML5 storage technologies as explained here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Unfortunately, Indexed Database is currently not supported by internet explorer.

Comment: I finally use LocalStorageDb https://github.com/knadh/localstoragedb on top of the HTML5 storage to get a db-like API on top of local storage.